# How to make openapi-generator generate model for importMappings anyway?

Tags: spring-boot, converters, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I know that `importMappings` prevents openapi's codegen from creating the corresponding model (see below) but I want it to be created anyway. Is there a way to do so? (I am using the maven plugin.)

> Sometimes you don't want a model generated. In this case, you can simply specify an import mapping to tell the codegen what not to create. ([docs](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#bringing-your-own-models))

In the end, what I want to do is using a custom [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) to convert type `A` to `B` and register it with Spring Boot. But, of course, for that purpose I need the generated API and everything behind it to use `B`. That is why I wanted to replace `A` with `B` by using the `importMappings` option. But I still need `A` to be created so the `Converter` can start from there (converting `A` → `B`) because otherwise I would need to parse the JSON string (yikes).

So, if you have a better idea to combine the `Converter` with openapi's codegen I am also excited to hear about that.

Comment: Nobody's got an idea?